# Data binding with async data loading and backgroundWorker

Tags: c#, asynchronous, windows-phone-8, backgroundworker, azure-mobile-services

I would very much appreciate feedback on how to do this properly.

I have panorama view in WP8 with 4 items.  One item is map element and rest 3 display data downloaded from Azure mobile service. In main page code behind I set up backgroundWorker and related events

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
        App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
    }

private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        RefreshBinding();
    }
```

And in MainViewModel.cs I have the LoadData method.

```
public async void LoadData()
    {        
        PanItem1 = await PanItem1Table.ToCollectionAsync<PanItem1>();
        PanItem2 = await PanItem2Table.ToCollectionAsync<PanItem2>();
        PanItem3 = await PanItem3Table.ToCollectionAsync<PanItem3>();
    }
```

RefreshBinding() just sets the ItemSources of the 3 panoramaItems to PanItem1-3 accordingly. For some reason the binding fails silently as the page is created/bound before the data is loaded and ItemSource has to be re-set afterwards.

Ok this looks quite good on paper, but in practice I have run into 2 details that cause me trouble.

1) bw_RunWorkerCompleted() gets called instantly, it does not wait for the async operations to finish (which I thought it would). And I had to add artificial sleep(3000) in doWork(). This is far from optimal as I can't be sure if the data is populated after 3s.

Is there a better way to do this? Can you somehow verify completion of the async operations?

2) For some reason occasionally this all fails, leaving the app completely empty. Only background image and titles are shown, and all content of every panoramaItem are empty and also the map fails to load completely.

I suspect this is caused by trying to do too many things at once. Is there a neat solution how to balance the workload? My best guess at this point is to use SelectionChanged event of panorama and download only the data that user is viewing currently. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: I'm starting to get a feeling backgroundWorker is wrong approach. It doesn't seem to add anything but unnecessary complexity in the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you wrote your `LoadData` incorrectly, you should write it like this:

```
public async Task LoadDataAsync()
{        
    PanItem1 = await PanItem1Table.ToCollectionAsync<PanItem1>();
    PanItem2 = await PanItem2Table.ToCollectionAsync<PanItem2>();
    PanItem3 = await PanItem3Table.ToCollectionAsync<PanItem3>();
}
```

Now rewrite the caller functions:

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
    App.ViewModel.LoadData().Wait();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
}
```

This way you will actually wait for asynchronous operations to complete. But this is still wrong, you should actually ditch the whole `BackgroundWorker` and just use asynchronous operations:

```
public async Task LoadDataAsync()
{        
    PanItem1 = await PanItem1Table.ToCollectionAsync<PanItem1>();
    PanItem2 = await PanItem2Table.ToCollectionAsync<PanItem2>();
    PanItem3 = await PanItem3Table.ToCollectionAsync<PanItem3>();
    RefreshBinding();
}
```

Comment: Noob question. As the LoadDataAsync is in viewmodel, and RefreshBinding is in MainPage, how can I make the call? And isn't it bad practice to add such dependancy?